# Format/bytes for sending XML to socket

Tags: c#, xml, sockets

I want to send two different lines of XML to a socket as follows:

```
         <GetServerTime UpTimeAtRequest="1919"/>

         <Subscribe FrontId="priceFeed" URI="ffo:/price/productCode=VP-4-6-"/>
```

I'm using Hercules to test this, but it won't let me send it in that format. How should I delimit or format the XML above so I can send it directly to the socket with Hercules after connecting to the appropriate ip address and port?

I would be happy to send this using a WebClient or something in C# also.

Thanks.

Comment: Is the socket in question *actually* implementing HTTP? If not, it's hard to see how WebClient would work...

Comment: Without knowing what Hercules is, it's tricky to know what's going on, to be honest...

Comment: Then you'll need to use the asynchronous methods on `Stream`. Or have two threads - one reading and one writing...

Comment: Well that's one way, yes. Or you can use `TcpClient` and asynchronous stream operations. Both should work fine.

Comment: Well, the docs for `Stream.BeginRead` would be a good starting point, but we're now a long way away from the original question...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've no idea what Hercules is, but sending arbitrary data over a client is easy:

```
using (var client = new TcpClient())
{
    client.Connect(host, porg);
    using (var stream = client.GetStream())
    {
        // Or some other encoding, of course...
        byte[] data = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(xmlString);

        stream.Write(data, 0, data.Length);

        // Whatever else you want to do...
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you eveeeeeer sleep? ^^ :)

Answer (score 0):

[WebClient](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tt0f69eh.aspx) is pretty simple to use (assuming your socket is using the HTTP protocol), so using [UploadString](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0645045y.aspx) would look something like this:

```
Uri uri = new Uri(@"http://www.mywebsite.com/someurl");
string myXml = "<insert valid xml here> /"

using (WebClient wc = new WebClient()
{
  wc.UploadString(uri, myXml);
}
```

I'd only worry that your xml isn't valid as it has two root nodes and no xml header.